# jupyter pillow draw text tabs to show squares?

Tags: python-imaging-library, jupyter, draw

When using Pillow to draw text in Jupyter notebook, \t tabs are still displayed as small squares. I have tried setting draw.textsize to a larger value and using monospace fonts like Courier, but it does not fix the issue. How can I properly display \t tabs as spaces when rendering text to image in Jupyter using Pillow

```
font = ImageFont.truetype("./font/SimHei.ttf", 36, encoding='utf-8')

img = Image.new("RGB", (1280, 1754), "white") 
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img, mode="RGB")
```

Comment: Please click [edit] and make sure your [mcve] is **complete** - it currently has no `import` statements, nor does it actually draw any text, nor does it show the resulting image.